# How bad is riding with road tires off-road?

Tags: motorcycle, tires

I am planning a small trip and from looking in Google Maps satellite view, it seems that a dirt road is leading to my accommodations.

As I have pure road tires, I was wondering whether I should change my plans or a small dirt road (about 1km go and back) shouldn't be any problem.

To make it clear, I am not planning any off-roading action, just a small dirt road leading to the hotel. Also, I am aware that riding with road tires off-road reduces traction and control of the motorcycle. I am planning to go extremely slow and careful and my question is mainly regarding **possible tire damage**. Should I avoid anything that is not tarmac, or such small dirt road wouldn't impose any notable damage?

If it is needed: I am riding a [Yamaha Tracer 700](https://www.yamaha-motor.eu/kv/kv/products/motorcycles/sport-touring/tracer-700-2020/) fitted with [Michelin Pilot Road 4](https://motorcycle.michelinman.com/motorbike/tyres/michelin-pilot-road-4).

Comment: I would worry more about safe stability than tire damage. Street tires don't offer much traction or steering stability on dirt roads.

Comment: @Moab I will admit that this will be probably my first time doing something like that (as this is my first "big cc" motorcycle), so I might be underestimating this issue. But I am planning on riding slowly and carefully and am mostly afraid of tire damage as they are expensive and new :)

Comment: Better to worry about damage to you and the bike if it goes down on a dirt road with street tires. Not knowing your riding skills or actual road condition, I advise proper off road tires.

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestions @Moab. I will surely take them in count

Comment: Travel safe my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to avoid tire damage is to pay attention to the path you take avoiding rocks and sharp stones. A short trip like that should not be an issue.

Probably the "road" has been "graded" or at least rolled as you say it leads to a hotel.

If the hotel is designed for serious off-roaders and you need 4wd and a winch just to get there then you have chosen the wrong hotel...

Comment: Yes I assume the road is not so bad and "off-roady" as it is used quite frequently. Anyway thanks for your suggestions, I will surely pay attention to big and sharp rocks and come back here when I'm back (assuming I make it :D)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this sort of thing many times on a KTM 1290 super adventure with the same tires as you - no issues at all. I am not an off road rider at all.

Just take it slow, upright, stay off the front brake and be gentle with the controls and you should be fine. Enjoy yor trip!